# Looping through chars, generating words and checking if domain exists

Tags: python, ping

Is there any way to generate words based on characters and checking if a domain exists with this word (ping)?

What I want to do is to generate words based on some characters, example "abcdefgh", and then ping generatedword.com to check if it exists.

Comment: Is there any way?  The answer is "Yes".  Is there something more specific you need to know?  Please post the code you have at the present time and any errors you're getting.

Comment: Are you trying to buy all remaining domain names?  :)

Comment: Hehe, no, it's a quiz I've been stuck with for hours, so I have some words I think might have a relevance to a webpage... So I want to check the characters from those words to check if any webpage is created with those chars

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to use the ping command, but you can use Python's [`socket.gethostbyname()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname) to determine whether a host exists.

```
def is_valid_host(hostname):
    try:
        addr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    except socket.gaierror, ex:
        return False
    return True

hosts = ['abc', 'yahoo.com', 'google.com', 'nosuchagency.gov']
filter(is_valid_host, hosts)
```

This is going to take tons of time and maybe make your ISP mad at you.  You're better off either:

1. Using a lower-level DNS interface such as [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/), or
2. Finding a direct interface to domain registrars, such as [whois](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=whois&submit=search), and querying that.

You aren't going to use this to spam people, are you?

Comment: Thanks :)
No, I'm not going to spam anyone ;), just trying to solve a puzzle

Comment: Asking the DNS and asking whois does not give you identical results. For instance, in ".fr" (and probably many other registries), a domain can be registered but not activated and therefore invisible in the DNS.

Answer (score 3):

Just because a site fails a ping doesn't mean the domain is available. The domain could be reserved but not pointing anywhere, or the machine may not respond to pings, or it may just be down.

Comment: Or the host doesn't respond to ping requests (like cnn.com)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are talking about permutations of character combinations. This has been a fairly well [published recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/190465/). That link should get you started.

One additional note, ping will not tell you if a server 'exists' or if the name is registered, only if it is online and is *not* behind a firewall that blocks ping traffic.